# Text not printing in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text

Nooby question - How do you write text in Inkscape?

It looks like I'm typing *something* in the text box, but no characters are printing:

[image]

Comment: Try a different font.

Comment: @Scott Yea I'll try that next time, it's something to do with the Tolkien font. I ended up opening a new document and then didn't have trouble writing in the text box. Weird.

Comment: Also check the group's (and its parent groups') transparency / visibility, in case it has nothing to do with the font, but with opacity / transparency / visibility settings.

Answer (score -1):

Try choosing different colors (dark ones) while typing. Or it will be visible once you finished typing.